# Mongoose population - callback vs exec

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

On Node.js/Mongoose/Mongo is

```
SomeModel.findOne({_id: id}, callback).populate('ref')
```

equivalent to

```
SomeModel.findOne({_id: id}).populate('ref').exec(callback)
```

"ref" is single doc (not an array).

The problem is that using the first syntax the "child" document is *randomly* not populated when callback is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the internals, but I'd say they are not the same.

The first probably does this:

- find the document
- call the callback with the document
- populate the ref (this is done through a separate query)

The second probably does this:

- find the document
- populate the ref
- call the callback when the ref has been resolved

The randomness that you're witnessing is because the *"populate the ref"* call, when fast enough, may populate the document before you use it in the callback. In other words: a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Comment: Yup, this is also my suspicion. I'll still keep it open to see if there is someone who knows it for sure

Comment: Ran an experiment, got similar result.

Comment: I'd agree, I had to do this as well and chose the second. Does what you say (hopefully forever), find -> populate -> callback